# Is it possible to compare parent element's attribute with child's one inside select XPath in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to compare two attributes values in my XPath select expression ... in the concrete, I want to compare type's tid attribute with person's category attribute. Is it possible to make it works? :)

```
<xsl:template match="/people/type">
    <div class="type">
        <h3>
            <a name="./{@tid}"><xsl:value-of select="./title"/></a>
        </h3>
        <ul>
            <lh>Persons with this type:</lh>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../employees/person[@category=@tid]"/> <!-- here I would like to pass attribute tid of an type element -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is easily possible if you put regard on the context of your expressions.

The context of your expression is `/people/type` created by `<xsl:template match="/people/type">`.

If you try to apply a different context `/employees/person[@category...]` created by `<xsl:apply-templates select="../employees/person[@category=@tid]"/>` you have two contexts. The contexts of `@category` and `@tid` are different.

The solution is simple. Just fix one context in an `xsl:variable`:

```
<xsl:template match="/people/type">
  <xsl:variable name="typeID" select="@tid" />  <!-- fixing @tid of '/people/type' to $typeID -->
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/employees/person[@category=$typeID]"/>    <!-- using $typeID -->
    ...
</xsl:template>
```